# Cakephp 3 Dynamic Chart display

Tags: cakephp, charts, cakephp-3.0

I would like to ask how to display charts dynamically at the view.ctp html page

the chart sample this is a sample chart link http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

at the controller page, i learned a method from a question thread here, and its ok for controller,  not sure how to display it out at the html page for charts

```
 $series = $this->Orders->find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'month',
            'valueField' => 'price',
            'fields'=>[
                'month' => 'MONTHNAME(created_at)',
                'price' => 'SUM(price)'
            ],
            'group' => ['month'],
            'order'=>['MONTHNAME(created_at)'=>'ASC'],
        ])
        ->where(['user_id' => $this->authUser['id']])
        ->toArray();

        $months = json_encode(array_keys($series));
        $amounts = json_encode(array_values($series));

        $this->set('months', $months);
        $this->set('amounts', $amounts);
        
        $this->set(compact('series'));
```

the Html display page, i added  within the div class, seemed like added wrongly

```
   <div class="widget-content tab-content bg-white p-20">
                <div class="ct-chart tab-pane active" id="scoreLineToDay"></div>

            
                <script>
                    new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
                        labels: [<?= json_encode($months) ?>],
                        series: [
                            [<?= json_encode($amounts) ?>]
                        ]
                    }, {
                        low: 0,
                        showArea: true
                    });
                </script>


                <div class="ct-chart tab-pane" id="scoreLineToWeek"></div>
                <div class="ct-chart tab-pane" id="scoreLineToMonth"></div>
```

can anybody show me some ropes of how to display it out?

thank you very much

Comment: You are JSON encoding the data twice. Compare your output to the documentation to figure the difference, wrapping the data in a nested array is probably incorrect too.

Comment: hello  ndm, thank you for your reply,  that's the problem where im not able to solve during the weekend,  do you mind show me the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `json_encode` from you method

```
$months = array_keys($series);
$amounts = array_values($series);
```

And also in label and value you don't need this `[]`, Just use

```
labels: <?= json_encode($months) ?>,
```

Comment: thank you very much,  it works :-).  by the way, i like/subscribed your youtube channel about  since last year, and enjoying learning from it.

Comment: hi Alimon Karim,  i got a question about your search query question based on learning from  your youtube channel,  will post a new question and ask for your opinion